# FIle Writer and Reading

Tags: java, filewriter

So I have created a code that is suppose to ask the user for a file name. If the file name does exist it is suppose to do the following:

Capitalize the first letter in the file and capitalize the 1st letter after every period and correct the spacing by removing any duplicate spaces so that there is only 1 space between words.

Write the modified output to a file named HomeworkOutput6-2.txt.

I was able to fully do this but have one very MINOR issue that I do not know how to tackle.

IF the user file had only 2 lines. The modified file has a third blank link. How could I eliminate that 3rd extra line.

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.FileWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class ReadAndEditFile {

          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = null;

// keep asking for a file name until we get a valid one
while (true) {
  System.out.println("What is the name of your file?");
  String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
  file = new File(fileName);
  if (file.exists()) {
      //enter code here
    break;
  } else {
    System.out.println("File Not Found " + fileName);
  }
}


scanner.close();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("HomeworkOutput6-2.txt"));

boolean firstLine = true;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

  if (firstLine && line.length() > 0) {
    // capitalize 1st letter of first line
    line = Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
    firstLine = false;
  }
  line = capitalize(line);
  writer.println(line);
}
writer.close();
br.close();
          }

          // remove extra spaces and capitalize first letter after a period
          private static String capitalize(String line) {
            line = line.replaceAll(" +", " "); // make all multiple spaces as a single space
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean periodFound = false;

int i = 0;
while (i < line.length()) {
  char c = line.charAt(i);

  if (c == '.') {
    periodFound = true;
  }
  sb = sb.append(c);

  if (periodFound) {
    // period is found. Need to capitalize next char
    if (i + 1 < line.length()) {
      c = line.charAt(i + 1);
      if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        sb = sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        i++;
      } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(c) && (i + 2 < line.length())) {
        // there is a space after period. Capitalize the next char
        sb = sb.append(c);                                   // append space. Note we will have only 1 space at max
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(i+2)));  // upper case next char
        i = i+2;
      }
    }
    periodFound = false;
  }
  i++;
}
return sb.toString();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

your logic is perfect but complicated.i am suggest you to write simple logic because if you getting any error you can solve easily.instead of using  loop and and complicated ,i have written simple logic according to your requirement.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadAndEditFile2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = null;
        boolean createOutputFile = false;
        // keep asking for a file name until we get a valid one
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("What is the name of your file?");
            String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
            file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {

                /**
                 * read all files lines and convert to stream
                 */
                Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file.toPath());
                String data = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                /**
                 * split all lines with dot(.)
                 */
                String[] sepratedData = data.split("\\.");
                String test = "";
                for (String seprateString : sepratedData) {
                    /**
                     * trim() will remove all space at begin and end of string,
                     */
                    seprateString = seprateString.trim();
                    /**
                     * convert first character to UpperCase
                     */
                    if (!seprateString.isEmpty()) {
                        seprateString = Character.toUpperCase(seprateString.charAt(0)) + seprateString.substring(1);
                        test += seprateString + "."+"\n";
                        createOutputFile = true;
                    }

                }
                /**
                 * remove more than one space to single space
                 */
                if (createOutputFile) {
                    test = filter(test, " [\\s]+", " ");
                    Files.write(Paths.get("HomeworkOutput6-2.txt"), test.getBytes());
                    lines.close();
                }

                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("File Not Found " + fileName);
            }
        }

    }

    public static String filter(String scan, String regex, String replace) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = pt.matcher(scan);

        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replace);
        }

        m.appendTail(sb);

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: this prints the entire file onto one line and does not separate lines

Comment: Since this is a homework question, this answer may be a bit overwhelming and may lead to just copy-pasting it without any understanding. It is a good solution, though.

Comment: Let me know i know if you have any doubts. I will explain in details.